# CefSharp - JavascriptObjectRepository with multipages

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have problems to understand my error with `ChromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository`

I can register my C# object with this method:

```
chromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("gui", myObjectIndex, true);
chromiumWebBrowser.Address = "index.html";
```

And the javascript code works correctly on my first page `index.html`:

```
$("mybutton").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    gui.onClickButtonChangePage();  // calls MyObjectIndex.OnClickButtonChangePage()
});
```

However when the page change, i want to change my object `myObjectIndex` to `MyObjectPage2`.

I'm trying to do it:

```
chromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.UnRegister("gui");
chromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("gui", myObjectPage2, true);
chromiumWebBrowser.Address = "page2.html";
```

And when I press the buttons on `page2.html`:

- 1. Get error

```
$("mybutton2").on("click", function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 gui.onClickButton2();  // didn't call MyObjectPage2.OnClickButton2() !
});
```

- 2. Do nothing:

```
$("mybutton2").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    (async () =>
    {
        await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("gui", "gui");
        gui.onClickButton2(); // Nothing happens
    })();
});
```

[wiki CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage)

Comment: Did you initialize the object in your javascript with `await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('gui', 'gui')`?

Comment: Only thing that will help you is adding a "RemoteDebuggingPort" in your CefSettings and then open chrome localhost:<thatport> and check the console to see what error you're getting. Happy debugging.

Comment: If your page shares the same origin then the object will be cached in the render process,  you can ignore the cache using example three in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#settings

Comment: And when should I use this method? @amaitland  because using this method on `page2.html` isnt useful :(

Comment: Explain why it's not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to call this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        CefSharp.DeleteBoundObject("gui");
        CefSharp.RemoveObjectFromCache("gui");
        CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("gui");
});
```

Comment: Don't call `BindObjectAsync` with the same param twice.